# How to specify a BigQuery table as an input source for the AutoMLImportDataOperator Airflow Operator?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-automl, automl

As per the documentation available in the Airflow Docs [here](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/automl/index.html), GCS can be configured as an input source for the AutoMLImportDataOperator. However, I'm curious as to how a BQ table can be used since there is functionality for it within AutoML Tables itself. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AutoML Tables [supports](https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/prepare#import-source) both BigQuery and GCS as sources. You can use BigQuery URI format to specify the location of your training data and it must conform to the following format: `bq://<project_id>.<dataset_id>.<table_id>`

In the Airflow DAG, you can use `AutoMLImportDataOperator` with `input_config` as below

```
IMPORT_INPUT_CONFIG = {"bigquery_source": {"input_uri": 'bq://{}.{}.{}'.format(project_id, bq_dataset, bq_table)}}

import_dataset_task = AutoMLImportDataOperator(
        task_id="import_dataset_task",
        dataset_id=dataset_id,
        location=GCP_AUTOML_LOCATION,
        input_config=IMPORT_INPUT_CONFIG,
)
```

You can refer to Airflow example DAG [here](https://github.com/PolideaInternal/airflow/blob/6c6af68341420176372d57d4ab35813b29bc9134/airflow/gcp/example_dags/example_automl_tables.py) for a more complete example with GCS as source. You have to update `IMPORT_INPUT_CONFIG` variable with BigQiuery URI.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment Airflow in GCP is still in prerelease [0], and as I understand there is no this functionality in Airflow operators [1] up to now. You may use the bigquery_to_gcs [2] operator to move your BQ data into GCS for later using the AutoMLImportDataOperator. Alternatively you can try to create your custom operator [3]

[0] https://cloud.google.com/automl-tables/docs/integrations

[1] https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator/gcp/automl.html

[2] https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_to_gcs.html

[3] https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/custom-operator.html